# Prisma & Supabase - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, prisma, supabase

I got the following error, while trying to populate my Supabase table using Prisma...

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm using NodeJ, and the following script

```
import { createRequire } from "module";
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const { PrismaClient } = require("@prisma/client");

const db = new PrismaClient()


const seed = async() => {
    await db.post.create({
        data: {
            email: 'hello@hello.com',
            name: 'hello'
        }
    })
}

seed();
```

I already performed migration successfully, the connection is working properly...

Comment: What is your Node version?

Answer (score 0):

experienced the same problem today.
switching the engine type to "binary" didn't work,but re-installing `@prisma/client` fixed the problem